# Managed DirectX9 Drawtext behind object

Tags: directx, directx-9, drawtext, managed-directx

I use the drawtext method to create labels on a grid. Works perfectly - but they are always in front of the mesh im showing in the grid.

Is there a possibility to render it behind the mesh that its not visible inside the object?

Seems like drawtext uses no depth buffer:-(

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the z-buffer:

```
Device.SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE,FALSE)
```